# python - PIL merging gifs

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, gif

Lets say I had two different gifs

```
gif1 = Image.open(filename)
gif2 = Image.open(filename)
```

Is there a way that I can merge them together? Or like stack them on top of each other?

Answer (score 0):

```
from PIL import Image, ImageSequence 
import sys, os 
filename = sys.argv[1] 
im = Image.open(filename) 
original_duration = im.info['duration'] 
frames = [frame.copy() for frame in ImageSequence.Iterator(im)] frames.reverse() 
from images2gif import writeGif 
writeGif("reverse_" + os.path.basename(filename), frames, duration=original_duration/1000.0, dither=0)
```

I think this is the solution or something that can be close to what you want to achieve

Answer (score 0):

I just achieved merging two GIFs the same way as creating GIFs from png-files via PIL.

**Example Code:**

```py
import os
from PIL import Image

gif = []

# Assuming you have a directory that includes only your GIFs
img_list = os.listdir()
# OPTIONAL: Sort them according to their file names
img_list.sort()
for image in img_list: append(Image.open(image))

gif[0].save('merged.gif', save_all=True,
            optimize=False, append_images=gif[1:],
            loop=10, duration=300)
```